# Undefined array key - Cookie not set

Tags: javascript, php

When my PHP code is called from browser, it works. When called from JavaScript, the cookie variable is `undefined`. It has three scripts. Front end PHP to select airline, passed to PHP to call the JavaScriptand display chart. The cookie is there in the application/cookie window. Of course if `airline` is hardcoded in the fetch program, it works. Tried AJAX and PHP variable retrieval which didn't work as expected. I don't understand why the cookie variable is `undefined` when PHP is called from JavaScript, but it works as expected when PHP is called from browser.
Appreciate any help on this.

Here is a snapshot from application window showing the cookie:
[image: snapshot]

Here is data from PHP run in browser with echo of airline and cookie array:

```
FedEx {
  "csrftoken":"Ajy5Fvg1A8gVHUN4Al5B4heZxn8LFuGFz1ZAPzcQWXJc7tQguB6yePtbmODOBCTh",
  "airline":"FedEx"
}
[
  {
    "Day":"Thursday",
    "XDate":"January-04-2024",
    "Time":"04:59:59",
    "Flight_Number":"FX1444",
    "Airline_Name":"FedEx",
    "IATA":"MEM",
    "From_Airport":"Memphis International",
    "IATC":"FLL","To_Airport
.
[
```

Here is fetch from network window:
[image]

Javascript

```
async function getData() {
       
      const response = await fetch('http://192.168.1.2:8081/airline_fetch.php', {credentials: "same-origin"});
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
```

PHP Cookie

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["airline"])) 
    $Airline_Name = $_COOKIE["airline"]; 
else 
echo "Cookie Not Set";
```

And just to reiterate, the PHP `airline_fetch` works when called from browser, but receives the cookie error when PHP is called from the Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Comment: This is mostly by design these days. Browsers have gotten a lot stricter with cross-origin cookies. Instead of trying to make this work, try to solve your problem in a different way.

Comment: I would guess the JS is on a different origin?

Comment: I've editted your question, but something seems to be lacking in the cookie `echo`ed by your PHP code.